# Why would defining `font-weight` affect loading time for large lists of data?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I work on an app (PHP), where we had delays in loading time.

Smaller lists would load within a second or two. Larger lists would take up to 30-45 seconds to display. Lists include checkboxes to manage the items listed.

At first, and in general, more data means things may take a bit longer to display.

Then, we narrowed it down to... CSS defining font properties on a pseudo-element?!?

```
el[data-updated-attr][type=checkbox].pretty + label::after { font-weight: bold; }
```

After removing `font-weight: bold`, the 30-45 second delay was just as quick as the smaller list(s).

We currently use `Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif`, but it also opens up the opportunity to test our `@font-face` properties as well as seeing if variable fonts (like Open Sans) run into the same issues while a page is rendering.

Comment: It's because that selector is horribly inefficient. Data selector, relative selector, AND a pseudo-selector all in one CSS rule.

Comment: (Shot in the dark) Try using a font face designed at a specific weight, e.g. get a 600 font, use it at font-weight: 600. Some fonts are artificially 'extrapolated' (right word?) to bold, so one designed at the specific weight you want, *might* load faster.

Comment: Maybe try removing that style from your CSS and instead use Javascript to re-style those `::after` elements after the document has loaded, either by traversing the DOM or simply injecting a new CSS style? It may end up taking just as long for the browser to render the changes, but at least it will have loaded and rendered the (unstyled) version first?

Comment: I suggest applying a class to the `label` and narrowing the selector to `label.class::after { font-weight: bold; }`. Performance should be significantly better. As @bob_cobb mentions the current selector is quite expensive (two attribute selectors, a class selector, an adjacent sibling combinator, along with an element and the pseudo element makes for a lot of work; an element, class, and pseudo element will be relatively lightweight). Of course, if you're doing this over several tens of thousands of elements, it's still going to take a while. Consider pagination or other progressive loading.